# On - off - on rocker wiring

Tags: switches

I am wiring an "on-off-on" style toggle switch from the AC mains to turn a power supply on and off. I don't need the second "accessory" line from the switch, should I just leave the third pole floating or tie it to the "off" pole? Thanks for any help

[image: http://images.lowes.com/product/converted/039008/039008774514lg.jpg]

Comment: do you have a photo of the component or other information that help us to make sure we know what you mean with the switch positions?

Comment: Yes, it is this SPDT switch: http://www.lowes.com/ProductDisplay?partNumber=543137-37672-393181&langId=-1&storeId=10151&productId=50107280&catalogId=10051&cmRelshp=req&rel=nofollow&cId=PDIO1

Comment: For safety, you may want to insulate the unused connection.

Comment: If you're using normal [insulated quick-connects](http://www.alliedelec.com/images/products/Small/70084055.jpg) you can put an uncrimped one on the spare connection to help insulate it as @Andrew suggests.

Answer (score 1):

As a simple SPDT switch, you have three options.

1. Leave the second throw unconnected. On-Off-Off
2. Connect the second throw to the center. Still On-Off-Off.
3. Connect the first throw and second throw together. On-Off-On.

Answer (score 0):

If your switch is indeed SPDT, just leave one of the end terminals not-connected.

If your switch has an internal indicator, you will need to make sure that the indicator voltage is the same as your supply voltage.

If you aren't sure, just leave the indicator terminal not-connected.